# OpenVPN: Setting client's ip address as route gateway

Tags: windows, routing, openvpn

I want to create an OpenVPN config entry which looks like this:

```
route 255.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 {CLIENT_IP_ADDRES}
```

Is there any way to accomplish this without hard-coding the client ip into the configuration?

If not do you have any other ideas how to add this route (on aWindows client) without assigning a static ip to the client?

Background: I want Windows to send UDP broadcasts to the tap-device.

Comment: Broadcasts will be forwarded to every recipient inside a broadcast domain. What do you really want to achieve with wanting "to send UDP broadcasts to the tap-device"?

Answer (score 0):

To tell a client to apply some route after connecting to OpenVPN, you have to use the `push` command, something like `push "route <address> <netmask> vpn_gateway"`

But the end result doesn't appear to match what you say you want to do - usually the Windows IP stack will create such a routing table entry for every interface anyway? Maybe you need to fiddle with route metrics on the client?

Comment: Indeed the route is created when the connection is established. But the metric is too high so other interfaces are prefered over my tap device. I foud out that setting the route as mentioned in the configuration will decrease the metric considerably. But any other reliable method to reduce the metric should be fine too.

Comment: @Manuel do also note that metrics in Windows may not be doing what you expect them to do, see e.g. http://serverfault.com/questions/255799/windows-vista-and-7-dont-honor-routing-table-metric